# Experiencing glitches on terminal Fedora 38

Tags: fedora, terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I recently switched from bash to zsh in Fedora 38. 
I have installed oh my zsh and have the following plugins.
`plugins=(git fzf tig zsh-autosuggestions)`

My terminal has been acting really weird. Part of it will disappear if I press `up` on the key pad and it has strange glitches when I paste stuff in with the middle mouse button.

Also when deleting a command by using backspace part of it will remain on the terminal but will have no influence over the new command I put in. (see picture 2 I cannot delete the `oc lo` but it acts as if I am at the start of the prompt so `ls --help` runs successfully)

I have some screenshots below showing some of the weird glitches.

For context I am using Terminology as my main terminal but I experience these issues with Konsole as well.

Is this an issue common with oh my zsh?

[image: unnecessary space added][image: oclols --help picture]

My primary prompt is defined as:

```
$ typeset PROMPT
PROMPT='[%n]$fg[blue][%m]%{$fg[white]%}$(git_custom_status)[%~% ]%{$reset_color%}%B$%b '
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your:

> ```
>  PROMPT='[%n]$fg[blue][%m]%{$fg[white]%}$(git_custom_status)[%~% ]%{$reset_color%}%B$%b '
> ```

While `$fg[white]` and `$reset_color` which presumably are the escape sequences that tell the terminal to change the foreground colour to white and reset the colours as defined by the `colors` autoloadable function are within `%{...%}` to tell zsh's line editor that those characters have zero-width on display, that's not the case of `$fg[blue]`.

```
$ autoload colors
$ colors
$ echo $#fg[blue]
5
```

That's a 5-character long sequence, but when sent to the terminal it only changes the foreground colour and doesn't move the cursor five columns to the right, but as you didn't tell it that, the line editor gets a misunderstanding of where the cursor is meant to be which shows when you try to move the cursor around for instance.

Here, while you could use [`%{...%}`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Visual-effects) around that `$fg[blue]` as well, in prompt expansion you don't need that. [Prompt expansion](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html) has [special directives to change the foreground and background colours](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Visual-effects): `%F{colour}` and `%K{colour}` (and `%f` and `%k` to reset to the default), so it should just be:

```
PROMPT='[%n]%F{blue}[%m]%F{white}$(git_custom_status)[%~]%f%B$%b '
```

That also assumes the `promptsubst` option is enabled and that the `git_custom_status` command outputs something that is a valid prompt string.